# Is it possible to create nuclear fusion using a simple electric arc discharge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

If we have a simple discharge tube filled by deuterium gas or even heavy water, and put tungsten electrodes close to each other to create a huge electric field, then using a megavolt generator to apply a few million volts arcing .

can significant fusion occur in this manner ? is possible to generate a large amount of neutrons by this way ?

if it is not possible to create fusion by this way , is it possible to create it by using very high amperage discharge to reach few millions degree temperature to induce fusion ?

if a fusion using this simple design possible , why it is not widely used ?

Comment: See http://www.fusor.net/

Comment: "if a fusion using this simple design possible , why it is not widely used ?" if you mean as a neutron source , because there are many neutron beams in reactors and van der graafs. If you mean for generating energy it is probably because more energy is spent than gained in the fusion process.

Answer (score 4):

One example of something like you are imagining was an experiment by Naranjo et. al. reported in [Nature Volume 434, p. 1115, 2005](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature03575).  They heated a pyroelectric crystal in a gas of deuterium, which resulted in large electric fields being generated from the crystal.  Deuterons accelerated by the field of the crystal hit a deuterated target leading to fusion at the targt.  This was all done on a desktop apparatus and has been repeated by others since then.

Comment: The link http://homepages.rpiscrews.us/~danony/Papers/2009/Pyroelectric%20crystal%20neutron%20production%20in%20a%20portable.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Dense Plasma Fusion is basically what you are describing! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_plasma_focus
Using (for example) a proton-Boron mix can cause aneutronic (no neutrons) Fusion, although electrode matter can cause contamination, and x-rays compound that, and can destroy the electrodes.
There are ways optimise/increase fusion, and many universities and private organisations write papers describing their efforts. Maybe start with https://focusfusion.org/

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'd call a DPF a "simple electric arc discharge", but it is a very active area of work.